# Restore a struct that satisfy a defined interface from JSON string

Tags: go, reflection

I am implementing a task poller (restore unfinished task from a database).

The task must satisfy a defined `Task` interface:

```
type Task interface {
    // Identifier returns a unique string of a task
    Identifier() string
    // Data should be persistent
    Data() interface{}
    // Execute a task
    Execute()
}
```

The data stored in database satisfy the following struct:

```
type Record struct {
    Identifier string      `json:"identifier"`
    Data       interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

When task poller starts, it read the stored data from the database, then (let's just ignore error handling for now):

```
r := &Record{}
result := database.Get(key)
json.Unmarshal([]byte(result), r)
```

we restored the saved data from the database into `r`.

A problem appears that I cannot call the `Execute()` method because `r.Data` is actually type of `interface{}` (`map[string]interface{}` more specifically ) other than type of `Task`.

How can I convert or transform the `r.Data` to become a struct that satisfies `Task` interface so that I can successfully call `Execute()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `r.Data` is actually type of `interface{}` (`map[string]interface{}`
>   more specifically).

You need a method set that satisfies the `Task` interface. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Task interface {
    // Identifier returns a unique string of a task
    Identifier() string
    // Data should be persistent
    Data() interface{}
    // Execute a task
    Execute()
}

type Record struct {
    Identifier string      `json:"identifier"`
    Data       interface{} `json:"data"`
}

type Data map[string]interface{}

// Task interface methods
func (d Data) Identifier() string { return "" }
func (d Data) Data() interface{}  { return nil }
func (d Data) Execute()           { fmt.Println("Execute()") }

func main() {
    r := Record{Data: map[string]interface{}{}}
    fmt.Printf("r.Data: %[1]T %[1]v\n", r.Data)
    if m, ok := r.Data.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        r.Data = Data(m)
    }

    var tasks []Task
    if task, ok := r.Data.(Task); ok {
        tasks = append(tasks, task)
    }

    for _, task := range tasks {
        fmt.Printf("%T: ", task)
        task.Execute()
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/SC9Ff8e-_pP

Output:

```
r.Data: map[string]interface {} map[]
main.Data: Execute()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :) Your solution seems doesn't satisfy the requirement, because of the `Data(m).Execute()` only allows to call `Execute` for `Data` instead of an arbitrary type that implements `Task` interface. The goal is to wrap the poller inside an individual package, introduce `Data` seems makes the code more invasive. Let's say we have multiple tasks in the database, we need to define a slice of `Task` so that we can retrieve task data from database one by one, therefore we need a way to concatenate `tasks = append(tasks, task)`, any thoughts?

Comment: @Euryugasaki: You asked how to handle a specific JSON related type, `map[string]interface{}`, If you have this or any other type that satisfies the `Task` interface, append it to `tasks` asd `Execute()` it..

Comment: umm. However, you defined the `Execute()` inside the package. Now assume we built the package called `poller`, a user wants to call the `poller` package, let's say `poller.Initialize()`, it is not possible to let the user implement `Execute` method inside `poller` package. What I was expecting is the `poller.Initialize(arg)` takes an `CustomTask` as `arg` to let the `poller` package know that `poller` is now handling type of `CustomTask` and then perform its `Execute()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution, I got some inspiration that I can finally cast a `map[string]interface{}` to an arbitrary `Task`: 

    `bytes, _ := json.Marshal(r.Data)`
    `temp := reflect.New(reflect.ValueOf(task).Elem().Type()).Interface().(Task)`
    `json.Unmarshal(bytes, &temp)`